# CUDA and Dev C++

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

I'm wondering if it is possible to use CUDA in Dev C++, any ideas?

Comment: This question is too vague. Be more specific. What are your requirements. Why do you want to use Dev C++? Have you tried alternatives that did not satisfy you?

Comment: Hmm, the reason is that I like Dev C++ and I just used to use it. Other reason is that I don't want to learn other IDEs cause they are too complicated.

Comment: And the requirements: to be able to write applications that will delegate much portion of complicated calculations to graphic card. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

Dev C++ is not supported by NVIDIA.

Sorry.

Comment: You will have to go with Visual Studio 20052/2008 on Windows.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I'm currently installing it. But I will also try with NetBeans - I found some tutor which explains how to use CUDA with it.